# sizeof (FTransform) less than sizeof(FMatrix), Why and how? ELI5?

Tags: c++, sizeof, unreal-engine4

I was trying to decide whether to use FTransform or FMatrix for a TMap.

Intuitively I thought sizeof(FMatrix) would be less than Sizeof(FTransform) -- But when I logged them out -

SizeOf(FMatrix) = 64 bytes Sizeof(FTransform) = 48 bytes

Can someone explain the size consideration behind it? I get that FTransform has Scale, Translation and Rotation and can converted to a Matrix. So How and why is FTransform a better option than FMatrix.

Thanks.

Comment: According to the documentation, `FMatrix` is a 4x4 matrix of `float` elements, which requires 4x4x4 = 64 bytes. Linear transformation in 3D may be represented by a 3x3 matrix, so a transform generally requires less information (in `FTransform`, different kinds of transforms are stored separately).

Comment: FTransform is not FMatrix.  You can go to the source and check what it contains.